# Mixing text and equations in Latex in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I'm using the Extensions -> Render -> LaTeX functionality in Inkscape to embed LaTeX font in my Inkscape svg document and I'd like to be able to control the font size. I've seen [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277266/how-to-set-the-latex-font-size-in-inkscape/686425#686425?newreg=557a7c8aaf824c439f8b91c8994cbb07) solution for doing so, but this is only for an equation and doesn't work with mixed input. If I wanted to embed mix equations with text, e.g. instead of just $x+y=4$ I'd like to write "The equation is $x+y=4$," how do I control the font size of both the text and the equation?

Answer (score 6):

People may find this interesting as well:

https://writetex.tk/

It's an Inkscape extension similar to Tex Text, with the difference that TK or PyGtk are not required.

Answer (score 4):

The [textext extension](https://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/) lets you call LaTeX from within Inkscape and insert its output back into your inkscape document. It also lets you define a custom preamble that will be used every time you compile a LaTeX code snippet. You can massage the preamble -- say, by saying `\footnotesize` or `\Large\sffamily` -- so as to match the appearance of the fonts you use within Inkscape directly.